# Javascript memory analyser: What does it mean if a Htmldiv element shows up in the heapsnapshot after the page is navigated away from?

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-leaks

So I am running javascript memory analyser in visual studio for my windows store app . I see that one of the div elements that belongs to a page  is showing up on the heap snapshot after we navigate to a different page.

I suppose this is a memory leak? if yes, what could be the cause of it?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Browsers (or the OS in your case?) are not necessarily in a rush to carry out their garbage collection. Try loading a page that is full of tons of memory intensive assets such as images/videos/flash. When memory is getting low garbage collection should become more aggressive.

If you still see the element then is there a common javascript file for the two pages? Does it reference the div? As long as there is a reference to the div it should not be garbage collected and that is the source of the leak. As javascript objects are always passed by reference rather than the actual object, it can sometimes be tricky to find and change / delete every reference. Particularly look out for any references in the global scope as these references exist (unless explicitly changed) for the lifetime of the script and so are often not garbage collected (depends on how clever the javascript environment is).